# How to add and remove different viewholders (say 2 viewholders) dynamically in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to create a timeline using recycler view. I need to dynamically add and remove 2 different types of viewholder at the runtime (Note: not the data, "ViewHolder!").
Each viewholder represent a different set of data and layout.
Help me to solve this.

Comment: A ViewHolder is just a representation of a position of the data on the screen, how you want to hide it and not remove the data from the List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solve would be to add both(all) smaller items to one item like this.

```
<OuterLayout
    android:style="@style/yourStyle">
    <InnerLayout
        android:style="@style/innerStyle1"
        ...interior elements i.e. text views/buttons/>
    <InnerLayout2
        android:style="@style/innerStyle2"
        ...interior elements i.e. text views/buttons/>
</OuterLayout>
```

In your java code then you simply need a function like this

```
public static void minimize(LinearLayout layout){
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams size = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,0);
    layout.setLayoutParams(size);
}
```

All you would need to do from the Adapter is to call minimize on the one you don't want. You will also need a  corresponding expand() function because of how a RecyclerView recycles the views. You may have to change the function above to work for your layout.

Comment: I am sure there are also plenty of other ways to do this but this seems the most efficient for what you need. Glad it works for you!